# What is checked in while "Checking whether a package can be installed"?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have persistent errors while checking if is possible to install a package I made. The error I see is that I don't have a package installed from the Rstudio builder. However, I do have it installed and it can be loaded (see below)

From [R packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/check.html), the advice doesn't tell you what is going on:

> **Checking whether package ‘XYZ’ can be installed**. R CMD check runs R
>   CMD install to make sure that it’s possible to install your package.
>   If this fails, you should run devtools::install() or RStudio’s Build &
>   Reload and debug any problems before continuing.

I followed the advice, it seemed to install another package, and it installed correctly. but still the `devtools::check` returned an ERROR.
There are some post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+checking+whether+package+%E2%80%98%E2%80%99+can+be+installed), about failing to pass the check. See the error message:

```
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘integration’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘Matrix’
```

The problem is that the Matrix package is up to date (I reinstalled it to make sure). But in a CI test it builds correctly.

What is done when "testing if installed package can be loaded"?

I looked into the source of tools, but I couldn't make sense of what is doing. 
It is running an internal `.install_packages` function while testing if `test_load` which seems to call `base::library` which seems to load the namespace.

Neither from Rstudio build window and from the command line and it can't build correctly using `devtools::check`. But I can check after:

```
R CMD build package
R CMD check package_X.Y.Z.tar.gz
```

Which resulted in only a NOTE

---

Relevant info, I moved some packages from one lib to another, which may have created some errors to packages that have compiled code. However I think it was just a few (~10) packages.

```
> library("Matrix")
> session_info("Matrix")
─ Session info ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
 os       Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS          
 system   i686, linux-gnu             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language en_US                       
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       Europe/Madrid               
 date     2018-10-22                  

─ Packages ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package * version date       lib source        
 lattice   0.20-35 2017-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 Matrix  * 1.2-14  2018-04-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)

[1] /usr/lib/R/site-library
[2] /home/lrevilla/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5
[3] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
[4] /usr/lib/R/library
```

Comment: Can you share your `DESCRIPTION` file? Might be something wrong there. No idea how the check handles multiple lib locations...

Comment: @JBGruber Well, I moved all the installed packages to a single directory, so it shouldn't matter. The [DESCRIPTION](https://github.com/llrs/integration-helper/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) file is correct.

Comment: I think the convention would be to check for the minimal version number of imports like `ggplot2 (>= 2.2.1)`. But I doubt that's the problem.

Comment: It just occured to me that it could be from the Rstudio, I checked the package from the terminal and it is passing the checks